# How to implement web-based Anonymity-Tests?

Tags: javascript, web, client-side-scripting

I recently came across some websites that demonstrate which information can be obtained from a user's system and show how 'anonymous' one is. For example these two sites here: http://ip-check.info/?lang=en or http://www.leader.ru/secure/who.html . So I became curious what information actually can be found about a web-user.

**1.) Which techniques can be used to gather information about a web-user**

From what I noticed they are using JavaScript, Java and Flash to gather all local information they can and send it to the server. Beside that, I'd like to know what other techniques can be used to gather information about the user's system or the user itself.

**2.) Where can I find resources to implement an anonymity test**

As I haven't done much web-programming I am interested in information and code to get started on an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one of the sites you listed [goes through what it does in detail](http://ip-check.info/description.php), so I would start there.